# How to Group a Yii2 model resultset by one of the attributes of the model?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

In my 'students' table, there are fields  'id', 'student_name', 'father_name', and 'class', such that

```
var_dump(Students::find()->All());
```

gives the following result

```
array (size=284)
  0 => 
    object(frontend\models\Students)[68]
      private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=10)
          'id' => int 1
          'student_name' => string 'VATS' (length=5)
          'father_name' => string 'KARAMJEET SINGH' (length=15)
          'class' => string '1st' (length=3)

    1 => 
    object(frontend\models\Students)[68]
      private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=10)
          'id' => int 2
          'student_name' => string 'VASHISHT' (length=5)
          'father_name' => string 'PARAM KUMAR' (length=15)
          'class' => string '1st' (length=3)     

        ......................
        ......................
        ......................
```

I want to use the 'class' field of the model as index like below...
e.g.

```
1st => 
    0=> 'id' => int 1
          'student_name' => string 'VATS' (length=5)
          'father_name' => string 'KARAMJEET SINGH' (length=15)
          'class' => string '1st' (length=3)  
    1=>  array (size=10)
          'id' => int 2
          'student_name' => string 'VASHISHT' (length=5)
          'father_name' => string 'PARAM KUMAR' (length=15)
          'class' => string '1st' (length=3)     

          ......................
          ......................
```

I have tried the `Arrayhelper::map($array,... , .. )` function, also the `Arrayhelper::index(..)` function. 
The `Arrayhelper::index($array, 'field_name_to_be_used_as_index')` seems to do the job, but it gives only one result for each 'class' type.
How can I achieve the array in above format?

Comment: use `asArray()` with query for more simplified result.

Comment: @RuslanBes, there are many more elements with different values of 'class' filed like '1st', '2nd' etc. that's why I put the .......... ......... below the results.

Comment: @InsaneSkull can you kindly give an example of asArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way to achieve this is to loop through and create a new array

```
$original_array = Students::find()->asArray()->All();
$grouped_array = [];
foreach ($original_array as $value) {
    $grouped_array[$value['class']][] = $value;
}
var_dump($grouped_array);
```

Comment: Though obvious, for future visitors I would add that you can use `ArrayHelper::toArray($model)` to convert the model to an array, after that Kandarp's Answer will work like a charm :)! Thanks.

Comment: you can use asArray with find() it will convert models to array, will edit the answer. Thanks